# I cant run js script

Tags: javascript, node.js

***hello all, is my script of discord bot***

**It's is my script JavaScrypt**

```
    const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();


fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("Couldn't find commands.");
    return;
  }
  

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} loaded!`);
    bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => { 
      bot.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
  
  });
});
})
bot.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.size} servers!`);
  bot.user.setActivity(`In Development`);
  bot.user.setStatus('online');

  bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    let prefix = botconfig.prefix
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let commandfile;

    if (bot.commands.has(cmd)) {
      commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd);
  } else if (bot.aliases.has(cmd)) {
    commandfile = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
  }
  
      if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

          
  try {
    commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
  
  } catch (e) {
  }}
  )})


bot.login("MTAwNzkyMDIyMDIyNjIwNzc2NQ.GldCmn.1jWZEr1ALjADcZvbAnDHkrhpy6OBlzpjcFMw8w");
```

**my error:**

```
      throw new TypeError(ErrorCodes.ClientMissingIntents);
      ^

TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\4bino\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:480:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\4bino\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\4bino\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\economybot-master\index.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ClientMissingIntents'
}
```

**I do not understand what to do, please help with this problem**
**I'm trying to run this script for the discord bot**
**I tried to look for a solution to this problem in other resources, but I didn't find anything**
**I have already installed the discord package.js but it looks like he can't find some module**
**My Node version.js is v16.16.0**

Comment: I think you just `require("discord")` ... no `.js` ?

Comment: I forgot to install Discord.js but only now another problem, edited the appeal

Comment: have you provided a valid intent for the client?

Comment: Yes, the script was downloaded and seemed to work for other users, but I had some kind of problem

Comment: And, if i just require("discord") no .js node js cannot search Discord.js